# In Java, how can I write an escaped Carriage Return in an XML Attribute?

Tags: java, xml

I need to serialize some data into XML and one piece of data is a string that has a carriage return (0x0D). I can't find a way to write this attribute with escaped syntax `&#xD;` syntax. When calling the `writeAttribute` method of `XMLStreamWriter`, it'll mangle the output as `&amp;#xd;` which is incorrect.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        XMLOutputFactory xmlFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8");
        XMLStreamWriter writer = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(osw);
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeStartElement("root");
        writer.writeAttribute("attr-with-cr", "foo\r");
        writer.writeAttribute("attr-escaped-cr", "foo&#x0d;");
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeEndDocument();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        String s = outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: XML 1.1 is okay, since the serializer can deserialize back. I kinda got somewhere with:

```java
xmlWriter.writeStartDocument("1.1");
// snip
s = s.replaceAll("\r", "&#xD;");
```

It seems okay, but I'm not entirely sure the repercussions.

Edit2:

---

Why this isn't a duplicate of:

> [XMLStreamWriter - Java 8 - writeCharacters - &#xd;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675481/xmlstreamwriter-java-8-writecharacters-xd)

This is for writing characters (inner node text), not attributes. Not applicable here.

> [XML Carriage return encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding)

The question asks what to do. The answer is the insert an escaped carriage return, which is the point of this question. *HOW* do you do this in Java?

Comment: Do you mean the XML parser is not escaping it correctly by itself? Please share a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding#:~:text=To%20insert%20a%20CR%20into,of%20the%20XML%201.0%20specification.

Comment: @aled I added the sample. It doesn't escape `\r`. And I found no way to do so myself.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675481/xmlstreamwriter-java-8-writecharacters-xd can be related.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes `&#13`; and `&#xD`; are the same (one decimal, one hex). But the question is how do I do that with Java?

Comment: @ShortFuse Your code already produce the value 0x0D inside the attribute `attr-with-cr`, what is the problem you have?

Comment: @Progman Java (`XMLStreamReader`) won't parse anything with `0x0D`. It'll throw an error about an invalid character. It **has to** be escaped. I don't know why it would write something it can't read, but here we are.

Comment: Due to [attribute value normalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize) in XML, any line break characters in an attribute value will be replaced with ASCII spaces eventually anyway.

Comment: I was able to confirm @VGR comment with libxml2 related implementations (xmllint and lxml in python). Even manually writing a new line, it's converted to space when reading.

Comment: It's interesting Java lets me write 0xD, which means I can go in and do a second pass and change it. That *works* and if I state XML `1.1` then `XMLStreamReader` won't complain about a `&#xD;` sequence. I think that's compatible?

Comment: Well, the question was improperly closed, but thanks anyway guys. I think I have it figured though by doing a second pass and using XML 1.1 in the header.